# Deploying ASP.net 2.0 application on old PC

Tags: asp.net, deployment, windows-server-2008

I need to test our ASP application + show it to the end-user. I can't find a good free host so I am trying to deploy it on an old PC.

Is it possible to install Microsoft Windows
Server 2008 R2 or Microsoft Windows
Web Server 2008 (I have no clue if both will work?) on my old PC, and let my asp application run on this machine?

(it would be great if someone could provide me with a guide)

thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

Are you sure that you need Windows Server 2008 R2?

ASP.NET application will happily run even on Windows XP with IIS 5.1.

Comment: I want the asp application to be accessible from anywhere (computer of end-user, for testing purposes only). Is that possible with XP + IIS 5.5?

Comment: Yes, it is possible. In fact, the only limitation of IIS 5.1 is that you have only one site (and cannot create additional sites). Apart from that, it's fully functional IIS with ASP.NET hosting feature.

Comment: Is there a free service that can provide me sort of domain name and point it to the application on my old pc so that the end-user can test it from his computer (completely different network)? Thank you!

Comment: You don't have to register the domain globally, instead ask your client to edit the local hosts mapping file (Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts) and add the mapping of the domain to your IP number. You can register any host name locally, you can even reregister some public host names like stackoverflow.com. More here http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hosts_(file)

Comment: Thank you! I created a vitual directory pointed to the folder with all the files (aspx, database,...) but when I point my webbrowser to the virtual directory, the application doesn't run but instead I get to see the file listing... Is there anything I missed?

Comment: When I ask the default.aspx page, the webbrowser tries to save the aspx source code on my file system.

Comment: Point your browser to any of *.aspx files. Also make sure that ASP.NET is registered for IIS with aspnet_regiis.exe -i. The last thing, make sure that the site settings allow scripts to be executed.

Comment: Is it required that I have anything running on the PC (I'm thinking of Visual Studio?)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/3420/discussion-between-jeroen-from-belgium-and-wiktor-zychla)

Answer (score 0):

It all depends on your client PC, but Windows XP has IIS 5.1 (though it's not installed by default).

Just zip your application, bring that zip into your client machine, unzipped into, for example, `C:\MyWebApp\` and create a Virtual Directory in IIS that points to that new location.

You're set to go.

*remember to bring a Windows XP Instalation CD with you in case that computer has not IIS installed*

**But I would go for a new approach**

Use **[Microsoft Webmatrix](http://www.microsoft.com/web/webmatrix/)**, download and installed in your client PC, then `right-click` your new location folder and choose `Open This Website in WebMatrix` and click `RUN`.

Classic ASP is fully supported in IIS 7.5 Express that ships with WebMatrix, and it's supported since Windows XP.

A very simple [how to](http://www.aspmessageboard.com/showthread.php?t=234864).